# MySQL counting rows from multiple tables returning exact same amount

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following SQL statement to `COUNT()` rows from two different tables. Only problem is that the `payment_count` and `upload_count` results always returns the same value.

If I only `COUNT()` from the `payments` table then the count is accurate, it's only when I count from both tables in the same statement does the `COUNT()` for both become the same `COUNT()` as `upload_count`. Hope that makes sense, how do I make it so the counts are individual?

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.name,
    COUNT(p.id) as payment_count,
    COUNT(b.id) as upload_count
FROM users as u
    INNER JOIN payments as p
        ON u.id = p.user_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders as o
        ON u.id = o.user_id
            AND o.order_status = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN uploads as b
        ON u.id = b.user_id
WHERE u.package != 1
AND o.id IS NULL
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) >= 6
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Use `COUNT(DISTINCT p.id)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)`

Comment: you're joining the tables in a "star" pattern, which is somewhat undefined territory. if one of those tables has far more matching records than the others, mysql has to fill in the holes by expanding/duping data from the smaller tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT() will count every non-NULL value it encounters.  It does not care if the value is distinct or not.  COUNT(DISTINCT fieldname) counts distinct values.  Use COUNT DISTINCT if you want to count unique values.